# POST variable doesn't echo in function

Tags: php, function, variables, output

I am currently learning the most basic PHP ever. I have 5 files.

index.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Budget Calcule</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<h2>Put in your: - </h2>
<form action="functions.php" method="post">
    <h3>Income</h3>
<label>Salary: <input name="salary" type="text" /></label><br />
    <h3>Outgoings</h3>
<label>Living: <input name="living" type="text" /></label><br />
<label>Insurance: <input name="insurance" type="text" /></label><br />
<label>Communication: <input name="communication" type="text" /></label><br />
<label>Loan: <input name="loan" type="text" /></label><br />
<label>Food & Drink: <input name="foodAndDrink" type="text" /></label><br />
<label>Entertaintment / Shopping: <input name="entertainmentOrShopping" type="text" /></label><br />
<label>Transport: <input name="transport" type="text" /></label><br />
<label>Other: <input name="other" type="text" /></label><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

this is my functions.php:

```
<?php

include('variables.php');





if(!($_POST['Submit'])){
        if(isset($_POST['salary'])){
        header('Location: output.php');
        return $_POST['lon'];
        }else{
        echo "All fields are required";
        }
}


?>
```

this is my variables.php:

```
<?php
$salary= $_POST['salary'];
$living= $_POST['living'];
$insurance= $_POST['insurance'];
$communication = $_POST['communication'];
$loan = $_POST['loan'];
$food = $_POST['food'];
$entertaintmentOrShopping = $_POST['entertaintmentOrShopping'];
$transport = $_POST['transport'];
$other= $_POST['other'];
?>
```

this is my output.php file:

```
<?php
include('outputFunction.php');
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Output.php</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php myText(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

and last but not least, this is my outputFunction.php file:

```
<?php
include('variables.php');

function myText(){
echo "Your salary per month is: " . $_POST['salary'];
}


?>
```

Now you're thinking "why have he split up his code in different files?" Well first of all, I split the variables from functions.php because I wanted outputFunctions.php to get the variables from variables.php so i could echo my `$_POST['salary']; . The function myText(); outputs the text just fine, but it doesnt output the $_POST['salary'];.

I do not know why it doesnt work, I just wonder if you could be my extra eyes and see if I've done some mistake.

PS! Don't down vote my question just because you think it's stupid. I am having problem with this issue and been working on it for hours without advancing anywhere.

Comment: It's because you're using a redirect from functions.php to output.php, with the `header()` call. When you do that, $_POST variables aren't passed around.

Comment: Yeah, `header('Location')` should always be followed by `exit`, but here it is followed by `return`. When you redirect, the PHP should be told to stop executing, since it will start again when the next request is received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

You don't need to include a variables.php file.  The variables you're accessing are global and you're just creating duplicates that aren't being used.  They also go away after the page changes since you're re-declaring them each page load.

You are also trying to call a variable that doesn't exist when you reference $_POST['lon'] instead of 'loan'.

And finally to actually answer your question:

**Your myText() function is referencing a variable that is not there anymore.**

You need to merge functions.php and outputFunction.php and output.php into one file so the variables aren't lost and all the processing is done without opening a new file each time.  I can see your original concept for separated files but an output file is going to be the file to process the input data from the form.

Now in your newly merged output.php, you should have something resembling this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Output</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
        if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
                if(isset($_POST['salary'])) { 
                        echo "Your salary per month is: " . $_POST['salary'];
                }
        } else {
                echo "All fields required.";
        }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

This means only two files - your form page and this page.

Comment: This doesnt work. And I need the variables if i'm going to store something?

Answer (score 0):

A few more tips:

If you want to check if the form was submitted, it has look something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){ ... }
```

Also, you should add a name="" attribute to your submit-Button:

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
```

And what is the variables.php for? You don't use any of those variables.

Comment: No I do not use the variables in those yet. That is because I want $salary to be echoed first.

Comment: How do i get myText(); to echo $_POST['salary']; or $salary in output.php?

Answer (score 0):

When you redirect the user via header() the data that is stored in the $_POST array gets lost.

You could directly redirect to ouput.php

```
<form action="output.php" method="post">
```

And do something like this:

```
<?php
include('outputFunction.php');

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    if(isset($_POST['salary'])) {
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Output.php</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php myText(); ?>
</body>
</html>

<?php

    } else {
        echo "All field required";
    }
}
?>
```

By the way you can always check what your $_POST contains with `print_r($_POST);`
This can be very useful for debugging.

Comment: @user2778213, in general I downvote OPs who use the phrase "it doesn't work", either in their original question or in response to someone's contribution. What was it about havana's assistance that did not work? Try to be as specific as you can.